# Can't access parent class properties

Tags: php, inheritance, visibility

When i use parent class properties it returns `NULL` , I have no idea why this happens, Example code :

```
class Foo
{

    public $example_property;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->example_property = $this->get_data();
    }

    public function get_data() {
        return 22; // this is processed dynamically.
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function __construct(){}

    public function Some_method() {
        return $this->example_property; // Outputs NULL
    }
}
```

Actually it happens when i set property values with `constructor` , But if i set values staticly ( e.g : `public $example_property = 22` , It won't return `NULL` any more

Comment: This is working for me. Can you please edit the post with the code you are using to get that property?

Comment: I used  @u_mulder answer , and it worked!

Comment: So you must have a `__construct()` in your `Bar` class, because otherwise it is inherited.

Comment: Yes actually i have , is it the reason?

Comment: Yes it is. If not called explicitly, `parent::__construct()` is overrided

Comment: @fpietka thanks , now i know the reason why it didn't work before :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because parent constructor should be called explicitly:

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function Some_method() {
        return $this->example_property; // Outputs NULL
    }
}
```

But looking closer - if you don't declare `Bar` constructor, parent one  should be executed. Maybe you don't show us full code?

So, if you have `__construct` in a child class and want to use parent constructor - you should call it explicitly, as I said as `parent::__construct();`.

If you don't have `__construct` method in a child class, parent's one will be called.

Comment: It is fortunately not needed.

Comment: extended class inherit constructor. from your example it should have worked right away

Comment: I don't know why this happens but after adding `parent::__construct()` it worked! o.O

Comment: Based strictly on your code example, `$bar = new Bar(); echo $bar->Some_method();` outputs `22`. @u_mulder changed my vote have your edit.